# IE9: Getting the value of 'MS Filter' property using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to read the value of a CSS property 'MS Filter'. This is my code:

```
<!--[if IE]> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var FilterValue = $(".imgshow-prop-display").css("-ms-filter");
alert("MS- Filter value: " + FilterValue );
});
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

This is the part of the CSS file which contains definition for the `imgshow-prop-display` class.

```
.imgshow-prop-display
{
  background: transparent !important;    
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4D90EE90, endColorstr=#4D90EE90);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4D90EE90, endColorstr=#4D90EE90)";    
}
```

I'm using IE 9 to test this. The alert displays the value "undefined". I have no idea why this is happening. I can read the value of the `filter` property though.

Comment: could it be that you don't have an element with that class?

Comment: @JibiAbraham I do have an element with that class. In fact, I can query for the property 'filter' or 'background' and get the correct values.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this for IE8 and had to get the individual properties from the filter:

```
// Get the non-jQuery native element.
var elem = $('.imgshow-prop-display').get(0);

// Get the properties.
var startColor = elem.filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient").startColorstr;
var endColor = elem.filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient").endColorstr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its just:

```
var FilterValue = $('.imgshow-prop-display').css("-ms-filter");
```

Note the dash >> `-ms-filter`

Comment: Sorry I typed it wrong. I was using "-ms-filter". Edited the question now.

Comment: @escist was just a thought. Where is this css defined though? Yea vaguely it shows undefined in IE9 and Chrome : http://jsfiddle.net/HRtzW/

Comment: It is defined in a separate file, which gets included only if the browser is IE. I'm new to CSS and Jquery, and I'm not sure whether I should be testing MS Filter in IE 9. 
I didn't get much info about this from the MSDN documentation for MS Filter [MSDN -ms-filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530752(v=vs.85).aspx). Will dig around more.